# Including image assets when releasing a Cocoapod

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoapods, nsbundle

I have made a custom Cocoa control and want to release it and write a podspec.

My control contains one image. **How can I package this image so that when others install my pod, my code can find the image?**

At the moment the image is included in the example applications Images.xcassets file and loaded using `[NSImage imageNamed:...]`. However, when others come to install my pod they won't want the example project: they will just want the classes and the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either include the files individually or with an `xcassets` file. Either way on the CocoaPods side you just need to include them in your spec as [`resources`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources)

Comment: I see. How do I then load the image from my code? If I include the image `xcassets` in the same folder as my source code can I just use `imageNamed:` as normal?

Comment: Yep you just load them like normal!

Comment: I'm having troubles with a private pod that includes a xcassets. and it's not being copied, any ideas? ```s.resource_bundles = { 'PodTarget' => [ 'Pod/Assets/*.xcassets'] }```

Comment: @CarlosRicardo did you find a solution?

Comment: @swalkner Didn't remember this post but I guess yes. On my `Core` subspec: `s.subspec 'Core'` I just have: `ss.resources = ['Pod/Resources/Fonts/*.ttf', 'Pod/Resources/Extra.xcassets', 'Pod/Resources/Mocks/*.json']`

Comment: I tried it in s.resources (did you mean to put one s @CarlosRicardo?) and I made the path in there match the path of my xcassets in finder as well.  Still didn't work for me.

Comment: @ScottyBlades _did you mean to put one s_
-
I guess I meant the subspec, that's why I used `ss`

Comment: @CarlosRicardo, oh ok.  Got it.